# How to use fontStyle on IOS? (with React-Native)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, build, fonts

I am trying to use the writing styles "bold", "italic" on IOS, but I encounter the following error:

```
Invalid RCTFontStyle 'bold'. should be one of: (
italic,
normal,
oblique
)
```

What I should change to no longer have an error when I build on IOS?

I don't understand because on android when i use `fontStyle: 'bold'`, I don't have the error and everything is working properly. I am novice, any help and simple explanations would be very appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use fontWeight instead.

```
fontWeight: 'bold'
```

or

```
fontWeight: 500;
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you very much for your help. =)

Answer (score 0):

`fontWeight` should be the correct prop to apply `bold` styling.

```
fontStyle: enum('normal', 'italic')
fontWeight: enum('normal', 'bold', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900')
```

see [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props#fontstyle).